# Oracle dedupe rows based on max values of 2 columns in conjunction

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, max

Was wondering if anyone knew an efficient way to dedupe records in a large dataset using Oracle SQL based on the max values of 2 attributes in conjunction.

In the hypothetical example below, I am looking remove all duplicate COMPANYID / CHILD ID Pairs by selecting first the maximum transactionid. Where the payload ID still has duplicates, the maximum BATCHID.

*note: transactionID and batchID may have null values (which would be expected to the lowest value)*

**Table: Transaction**

```
<p> CompanyID| ChildID | transactionid| BatchID | Product Details </P>
<p> ABC         EFG       306                    Product1 </p>
<p>ABC         EFG       306          54        Product2</p>
<p>ZXY         BFG       405          003       Product1</p>
<p>ZXY         BFG       405          004       Product2</p>
<p>ZXY         BFG       407                    Product3</p>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<p>ABC | EFG | 306 | 54 | Product 2  --selected on basis of highest transactionid and batchid </P>
<p>ZXY | BFG | 405 | 407 | Product 3 --selected on basis of highest transactionid </p>
```

I envisioned simply:
1) Using a max function on the transactionid and subquerying the result to max the batchID in addition
2) Self joining the "de-duped' set to the original set to obtain product information

Does anybody know of a more efficient / cleaner way to achieve this and a way to handle the nulls better?

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 11g, you can use this kind of requests:

```
with w(CompanyID, ChildID, transactionid, BatchID, Product_Details) as
(
  select 'ABC', 'EFG', 306, null, 'Product1 ' from dual
  union all
  select 'ABC', 'EFG', 306, 54, 'Product2' from dual
  union all
  select 'ZXY', 'BFG', 405, 003, 'Product1' from dual
  union all
  select 'ZXY', 'BFG', 405, 004, 'Product2' from dual
  union all
  select 'ZXY', 'BFG', 407, null, 'Product3' from dual
)
select w.CompanyID,
       w.ChildID,
       max(w.transactionid)   keep (dense_rank last order by nvl(w.transactionid, 0), nvl(w.batchid, 0)) max_transactionid,
       max(w.batchid)         keep (dense_rank last order by nvl(w.transactionid, 0), nvl(w.batchid, 0)) max_batchid,
       max(w.Product_Details) keep (dense_rank last order by nvl(w.transactionid, 0), nvl(w.batchid, 0)) max_Product_Details
from w
group by w.CompanyID, w.ChildID
;
```

The `nvl` function allows you to handle null cases. Here is the output (which does not fit yours, but I did the request as I understood what you wanted):

```
COMPANYID    CHILDID    MAX_TRANSACTIONID    MAX_BATCHID    MAX_PRODUCT_DETAILS
ABC          EFG        306                  54             Product2
ZXY          BFG        407                                 Product3
```

**EDIT**: Let me try to explain further `DENSE_RANK` and `LAST`: inside a `GROUP BY`, this syntax appears as an aggregate function (like SUM, AVG...).

- In a group, the `ORDER BY` gives the sorting (here, transactionid and batchid)
- then the `DENSE_RANK LAST` states that you will focus on the last ranked row(s) of this sorting (you can have indeed several rows with same rank)
- the `MAX` takes the maximum value inside these top-ranked rows. Most of the time, you only have one row so `MAX` can appear useless, but it is not. So you will often see `MIN` and `DENSE_RANK FIRST`, or `MAX` and `DENSE_RANK LAST`.

Here is [the Oracle doc on this subject](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions065.htm#SQLRF51411).

Comment: Thanks for that!. Apologies my output that i quoted earlier was incorrect. Your suggestion worked perfectly and very fast. If you dont mind, could you please explain how the dense_ranking is working here. In particular with the max_product_details. From what I understand it is ranking based on transaction_id and batch_id keeping/displaying only the last record (ascending - thus the largest). The function is a bit foreign to me, so I am still getting my head around it. This will definitely be useful in future though!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are dealing with multiple columns, you should also consider just using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CompanyId, ChildId
                                order by transactionid desc nulls last, BatchID desc nulls last
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `keep/dense_rank` method is fast. I'm not sure if doing it multiple times is faster than using `row_number()`.  Testing can give you this information.

Comment: `MAX` suggests the opposite of the `ASC` sort.  Also, the request to drop null values in priority can be expressed as a `NULLS LAST` option on the same statement, as in:  `ORDER BY transactionid DESC NULLS LAST`.  That is a little more explicit, and depends less on whatever default behaviors exist on the db.

Comment: @RichardPascual . . . You are right on both those counts and the query is fixed.  I'm actually curious from the OP on how this performance relative to the multiple `keep` statements.  (I upvoted the other answer.)